# SQL queries: how to add "sum" along with the corresponding data

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

I have a many-to-many relationship and I'd like to select sum of a specific field, along with all the necessary data. I'll just explain my case through the code.

Firstly, here are the relevant table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id`    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name`  text,
    `description`   text,
    `price` float,
    `picture`   varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `orders_products` (    
        `id`    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        `quantity`  integer,
        `status`    boolean,
        `product_id`    integer,
        `order_id`  integer,
        FOREIGN KEY(`product_id`) REFERENCES "products" ( "id" ),
        FOREIGN KEY(`order_id`) REFERENCES "orders" ( "id" )
    );

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `id`    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `created_at`    datetime,
    `updated_at`    datetime,
    `user_id`   integer,
    FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES "users" ( "id" )
);
```

Basically what I've done now, is this:

```
select 
"products".name,
"products".price,
"orders_products"."order_id",
"orders_products"."product_id"
from "products" 
inner join "orders_products" on "orders_products"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
where "orders_products"."order_id" in (1, 2)
```

This produces the following result:

```
name            price   order_id    product_id
"coca cola"     "2.35"      "1"     "1"
"snickers"      "1.25"      "1"     "2"
"snickers"      "1.25"      "2"     "2"
"popcorn"       "1.19"      "2"     "3"
```

However, if I'd like to "sum" the price, and order it based on order_id:

```
select 
sum ("products".price) as _sum,
"products".name,
"products".price,
"orders_products"."order_id",
"orders_products"."product_id"
from "products" 
inner join "orders_products" on "orders_products"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
where "orders_products"."order_id" in (1, 2)
group by "orders_products"."order_id"
```

I get the following result:

```
_sum    name        price   order_id    product_id
"3.6"   "snickers"  "1.25"      "1"     "2"
"2.44"  "popcorn"   "1.19"      "2"     "3"
```

What I'd actually like:

```
name            price   order_id    product_id    _sum
"coca cola"     "2.35"      "1"     "1"            "3.6"
"snickers"      "1.25"      "1"     "2"            "3.6"
"snickers"      "1.25"      "2"     "2"            "2.44"
"popcorn"       "1.19"      "2"     "3"            "2.44"
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is project the `sums` for each `order id` as a derived table, and then join your original query back to the derived table, which will allow you to show the `sum` as a column for each order:

```
select 
  p.name,
  p.price,
  op.order_id,
  op.product_id,
  Totals.theSum
from products p
  inner join orders_products op on op.product_id = p.id
  inner join
  (select sum(p.price) as theSum,
    op.order_id
   from products p 
     inner join orders_products op on op.product_id = p.id 
   where op.order_id in (1, 2)
   group by op.order_id) AS Totals
on Totals.order_id = op.order_id;
```

The filtering has already been done on the inner derived table, so won't need to be repeated.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5e1f4/1)

Comment: thank you for the changes in the original post, now it works perfectly!

Comment: actually, I've changed the sql a bit, as can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/javascrewpt/4564a6cf359c847131a5 , basically I've put the `where op.order_id in (1, 2)` out of the `select` of the `inner join`. Does this change things at all?

Comment: It won't change the results (since is inner join), but it may impact performance - If you look at the two execution plans (links at the bottom) of the [two Fiddles](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fe392/1) you will note different execution plans), although to be honest, we'll need much more data to be sure. Make sure you index the foreign keys (I've done this). If the performance really drops off, consider applying the filter in both the derived table `Totals` and in the outer query.